# C#: sort list of objects by DateTime property that is nullable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of objects: `List<FakeObject> list = ...`

Each object has a DateTime property, let's call it "Date"

I want to sort this list by this date property in descending order. However, when I try

`list.Sort(new Comparison<FakeObject>((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.Date, y.Date)))`

it complains because the Date property can be nullable.

How do I sort this list, where it treats nullable dates as MAX DATE, so it appears in the top? The quick easy alternative for me is to NOT make the Date field nullable, but let's suppose that's not an option right now.

In short: How do I sort a list of objects by DateTime, if the DateTime can be null?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One possible approach might be:

```
list.Sort(new Comparison<FakeObject>((x, y) => 
    -DateTime.Compare(x.Date ?? DateTime.MaxValue,
        y.Date ?? DateTime.MaxValue)));
```

**UPDATE:** modified to use `MaxDate` after the OP edited the question for clarification.

Note that you could do this either way (`MinDate` or `MaxDate`). The bottom line is this, if it's `null` then give it some static value that accomplishes what you want.

Comment: This also sorts the date in descending order?

Comment: @HenleyChiu, no this does not sort it `DESC`. To do that just add a call to `Reverse` at the end.

Comment: It'd be more efficient to make the `Sort` descending: either swap `x` and `y` or put a `-` (or `-1 * ` if you find that clearer) in front of `DateTime.Compare`. (also, as written, it doesn't compile. `Sort` returns `void`, not the list)

Comment: @TimS., now that's an interesting approach. Please verify my edit is correct.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to convert all null dates to the max date value then just do that in your function.  You can use the null coalesce operator for a more succinct syntax for this:

```
list.Sort((x, y) => 
    DateTime.Compare(x.Date ?? DateTime.MaxValue, y.Date ?? DateTime.MaxValue))
```

Comment: +1 my friend, I'm very happy that my answer mimics yours, it's humbling!

Answer (score 6):

If you can replace the list, instead of modifying it in-place, you can use LINQ.

```
list = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date ?? DateTime.MaxValue).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just setting the null date instances to MAX before the comparision?

```
list.ForEach(x => x.Date = x.Date ?? null : DateTime.Max : x.Date);
```

...followed by the call to your compare..

Comment: That *mutates the values in the list* which appears to not be desirable, he simply wants to use that as the effective value when sorting.

Comment: Aah.. yes, fair enough!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this.

First, given a class like this

```
class Widget
{
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get ; set ; }
}
```

I'd write a custom comparer, something like this:

```
class Widget
{
  public DateTime? DateCreated { get ; set ; }
}

class WidgetComparer : IComparer<Widget> , IComparer<DateTime?>
{
  public bool NullCollatesHigh { get ; private set ; }
  private WidgetComparer( bool nullCollatesHigh )
  {
    this.NullCollatesHigh = nullCollatesHigh ;
    return ;
  }

  public int Compare( Widget x , Widget y )
  {
    int cc ;

    if      ( x == null && y == null ) cc = 0 ;
    else if ( x != null && y != null ) cc = Compare( x.DateCreated , y.DateCreated ) ;
    else if ( NullCollatesHigh       ) cc = x == null ? +1 : -1 ;
    else                               cc = x == null ? -1 : +1 ;

    return cc ;
  }
  public int  Compare(DateTime? x, DateTime? y)
  {
    int cc ;

    if      ( x == null && y == null ) cc = 0 ;
    else if ( x != null && y != null ) cc = DateTime.Compare( x.Value , y.Value ) ;
    else if ( NullCollatesHigh       ) cc = x == null ? +1 : -1 ;
    else                               cc = x == null ? -1 : +1 ;

    return cc ;
  }

}
```

Then it's a simple matter of

```
widgetList.Sort( new WidgetComparer( true/false ) ) ;
```

where `true` specifies to collate nulls higher than anything else and `false` to collate them lower than anything else.

Comment: I already chose an answer... and it was just 1 line, much simpler than yours. Thanks.